# After upgrade Flutter 3.3.0 RaisedButton showing error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the type 'CartScreen'. (undefined_method

Tags: flutter, flatbutton

[image: Editor with error messages]

```
FlatButton(
  child: Text('ORDER NOW'),
  onPressed: () {
    Provider.of<Orders>(context, listen: false).addOrder(
      cart.items.values.toList(),
      cart.totalAmount,
    );
    cart.clear();
  },
  textcolor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can  check [breaking-changes/buttons](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons#context)

[image]

To have the same visual look

```dart
final ButtonStyle flatButtonStyle = TextButton.styleFrom(
  foregroundColor: Colors.black87,
  minimumSize: Size(88, 36),
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2.0)),
  ),
);

TextButton(
  style: flatButtonStyle,
  onPressed: () { },
  child: Text('Looks like a FlatButton'),
)
```

You can find more about [restoring-the-original-button-visuals](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons#restoring-the-original-button-visuals)

Comment: TextButton.styleFrom's primary prop has been replaced with foregroundColor

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Flutter 3.3.0 release notes](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-3.3.0), the deprecated `RaisedButton` was removed in [GitHub pull request #98547](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/98547).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add velocity_x: ^3.2.1 in your pubsec.yaml file