# Deprecated widget in flutter Flattbutton

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, deprecated

dears, I cloned a simple project from Git hub .
It shows me a tons of error such as   Flatt button,
is there any solution to use and lunch this project in Vscode.? or I should renew  each peace of code which is deprecated?
here is the example: git address:
(gh repo clone asjqkkkk/flutter-todos)

Answer (score 1):

If your flutter version is 3.x.x than `FlatButton`  and `RaisedButton` are deprecated. You have to switch them with `OutlinedButton`. Here is well explained [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73583533/11647876).

Answer (score 0):

1.first clean your project using `flutter clean`.

2.after that run `flutter pub get`.

3.buid your app