# How can I remove Cupertino library in flutter? how to use RaisedButton instead of CupertinoButton?

Tags: flutter, button

I can't use RaisedButton in flutter because I use **Cupertino** library. The error is :

```
lib/main.dart:24:15: Error: The method 'RaisedButton' isn't defined for the class 'MyApp'.
 - 'MyApp' is from 'package:myflutter/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'RaisedButton'.
              RaisedButton(
```

if I use CupertinoButton, it is ok but I want to use RaisedButton. I add

```
*import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';*
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you include your flutter version

Comment: Flutter 3.3.10 Engine • revision 3316dd8728 Tools • Dart 2.18.6 • DevTools 2.15.0

Comment: Similar question & possible duplicate [After upgrade Flutter 3.3.0 RaisedButton showing error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the type 'CartScreen'. (undefined_method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73583436/10157127)

Answer (score 0):

`RaisedButton` has been replaced with `ElevatedButton`. You can override the style to get the same effect.

Snippet from doc.

```dart
final ButtonStyle raisedButtonStyle = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
  onPrimary: Colors.black87,
  primary: Colors.grey[300],
  minimumSize: Size(88, 36),
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2)),
  ),
);
ElevatedButton(
  style: raisedButtonStyle,
  onPressed: () { },
  child: Text('Looks like a RaisedButton'),
)
```

[image]

Find more about [restoring-the-original-button-visuals](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons#restoring-the-original-button-visuals)